# Get the exact highcharts data which was used to render a chart

Tags: highcharts

Is there any way in High Charts to get the exact data which was used to render a chart?
I have already tried using "options" but it returns the whole JSON structure. I only need the data with which the chart was rendered.

```
{
    "chart": {
        "marginRight": 80
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "categories": [
            "Jan",
            "Feb"
        ],
        "title": {
            "text": "xAxisName"
        }
    },
    "series": [
        {
            "data": [
                29.9,
                71.5
            ]
        },
        {
            "data": [
                144,
                176
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For example, if I had rendered a chart using the above object, I need to retrieve the same object after the chart has rendered.

Comment: If you want to get raw data as was input in the options then you can take it from chart.options.series.data.

Comment: Should have been for specific. My bad. I have updated the question. I need whatever properties I have specified for that chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get those options via `chart.userOptions`.

http://jsfiddle.net/zd3q8t2L/

Comment: Thank you so much but I can't find this api anywhere. Isn't this documented? I want to know more about it. I'm able to get the object with which I rendered the chart but how far does it stands true. What if the chart is updated after it has been rendered! Say suppose I have updated/added a series or change the chart title, will I get the updated options object.